# iphone OS lower than 4 ==> Testing iAd?

Tags: iphone, iad, ios3.0

I implemented iad to my app (sdk 4), i set the target to be able to run OS 3 and higher
now i need to test and make sure that devices with OS 4 lower won't crash because of iAd.
Is there a way to go back to iphone OS 3.2 to test this.
Where can i download it, apple has removed it from their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you install sdk 4, sdk 3.2 should still be there as that is the separate iPad OS, in the top left corner of the code editor just select the dropdown and choose 3.2 (device or simulator)

Comment: thanks. Good point, i tested it with ipad simulator 3.2
but is the OS 3.2 on the ipad the same as the OS 3.2 on iphones?

Comment: No, the iPhone is 3.1.3 or 4.0 - 3.2 never came to the iPhone, eventually 3.2 will merge up into 4.0 on the iPad.  If possible, you are better off having a 3.0 device to test on OR in theory you might try installing an older SDK in addition to the current iOS4 final.

Comment: Yes, if you are targeting 3.x devices with this application, you need to somehow find a 3.x device to run your application on before submission.

Comment: you could downgrade you iPhone/iPod to 3.1.2 (not 3.1.3 though, just search for ipod firmware on google. And then google instructions on how to downgrade.